# XCode Update frames distorts view but looks great on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

After I click on "Update Frames" the subviews get re-arranged until they are not visible, however when I test the application the views look as expected in the  Simulator. I can make them both match but that would mean for me to update all the views in XCode. Is there  a better way?

[image: Update Frames]

[image: SubView]

Comment: This happens when you constraints are wrong. Fix your constraints.

Comment: Thanks @dasdom, I have done several things including removing all constraints, setting specific simulated matrics and still having this issues. I will take a look at the link in the accepted response to find more clues on where I am messing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto Layout issues occur when you create ambiguous or conflicting constraints.

Follow  this  link  :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/ResolvinganItemsLayoutIssues.html

This  will  clear  your  concepts  about  auto  layout.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have read several posts, the docs, and watched videos. However this is a subject I am still struggling with.

Comment: This is the topic which requires a lots of practical implementaion and one more thing always avoid using add missing constraints, rather try to do it correct while applying constraints.

Comment: The difficult and confusing part here is that the simulator displays the proper layout but XCode doesn't. Is there a way to get them in sync or get XCode to match Simulator? In my case Simulator looks as expected.

Comment: While applying constraints for layout, in assitant editor open preview for the storyboard for all the i-phone screens. That way you may sync xcode and the simulator.